# how to find the count of empty text boxes?

Tags: jquery

How to find the count of empty text boxes?

```
$('input:text.jqValueText[value=" "]').length
```

This is working partially. But if i enter empty space, this fails...

is there any way to find the empty textbox in single line... it should not accept empty space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this one:**

**HTML:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" CssClass="txt"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="txt"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="txt"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" CssClass="txt"></asp:TextBox>
```

**JQuery:**

```
var vEmptyTextBox = $(".txt").filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).val()) == '';
}).length;
alert(vEmptyTextBox);
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

sorry

try http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

```
$.trim($('input:text.jqValueText[value=" "]')).length
```

EDIT:

@ThiefMaster you're dead right:

how about:

```
var count = 0;

$.("input[type=text]").each(function(){
   if($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0)
   {
      count++;
   }
});
```

Comment: -1, @Rob, note ThiefMaster's comment, maybe consider `value^=" "` to partially solve that issue (you still won't be counting totally empty ones that way). More importantly, `$.trim()` accepts a string (see the docs you yourself linked to), but you are passing a jQuery object. Maybe rethink your answer - either by writing a loop that uses `$.trim()` or a jQuery `filter()`. As it stands, your answer doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

`$('input:text[value=""]').length;`

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom selector `:emptyValue` for this purpose:

```
$.expr[':'].emptyValue = function(obj) {
    return $.trim(obj.value) == '';
};
```

If you want it to work for selectboxes, too, replace `obj.value` with `$(obj).val()`